# Why are my then statements not working in my promise?

Tags: javascript, html, promise

There is a promise in a function that is called when a form is submitted. Every time I submit the form, an error message is returned from the `.catch`, after the 1st time the form is submitted. The first time it is submitted, nothing is shown on the console. After that, it is always the error message. After the 1st time, the url changes from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?`.

In the promise, the API is fetched from `/emails`, so could the error be because it maybe search for `/?/emails` instead of just `/emails`?

So, why is nothing shown on the console from the `.then`? I am new to javascript so please explain if I did something wrong?

js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    ...

    // Submit email
    document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', submitEmail)
});

function submitEmail() {
    fetch('/emails', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            recipients: 'person@example.com',
            subject: 'Hello',
            body: 'Hello, world!'
        })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            // Print result
            console.log(result); # this does not work
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: idk something happened', error); # the error message that is shown
            # the error parameter does not actually show anything either, just the string is shown on the console
        });
}
```

html:

```
<form id="compose-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-new" />
</form>
```

Comment: Since, we can't see the server-side code or run this ourselves, it's a bit hard for us to debug it further.  One possibility is that you need to set the `content-type` on the POST to `application/json`.  Another possibility is that the server isn't configured properly for this request.

Comment: You can also change this:  `.then(response => response.json())` to `.then(response => { console.log(response.ok, response); return response.json()})` to get more info on the raw request response, including the status and headers.

Comment: It didn't change anything. The console still showed the same thing I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Where should I put the `content-type`? I tried adding it under the `method: POST` but it would not allow me to add a dash

Comment: See my answer below for multiple improvement suggestions and more complete debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest setting the `content-type` to `application/json` and add additional debugging on the initial response so you can learn more about what's going on:

```
function submitEmail(event) {
    // prevent default form submission
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('/emails', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            recipients: 'person@example.com',
            subject: 'Hello',
            body: 'Hello, world!'
        }),
        // make sure the server knows this is a JSON body
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }).then(response => {
        // add additional debugging on initial response object
        console.log(`response.ok is ${response.ok}`);
        console.log(`response.status is ${response.status}`);
        console.log(`response.statusText is ${response.statusText}`);
        return response.json();
    }).then(result => {
        // Print result
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(`error.message is ${error.message}`);
        console.log(`error.stack is ${error.stack}`);
        console.log('Error: idk something happened', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: @tices - I added one more item to my answer to prevent default form submission.  It may be that you aren't blocking the default form submission and that is changing the page before your custom submit finishes and thus you don't see the output.